# MySQL Workbench error while accessing configuration

Tags: configuration-files, mysql-workbench

After installing MySQL Community Server 5.59 (64bit) and MySQL Workbench 5.2.31a and setting it up I try accessing the db's configuration and receive the following error:

> Configuration file 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\my.ini' can not be found. New file will be created on apply of changes.

I click OK. Then when trying to apply any change I get a second IO Error for not being able to write to the file.

It figures as my installation is at `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5` and not at `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0`. But why does Workbench search there?

Comment: Because workbench is a peice of @#$%. Workbench does not keep up with mysql. Every time there is a change to mysql almost everything breaks in workbench (in the latest workbench even simple things don't work - like adding a user http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58938). I wouldn't rely on it for anything. I have encounted nothing but endless crashes and error message while trying to do the simplest of tasks.

Comment: @Myforkwik - I think that's actually an answer, I'll accept it if you write it :)

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue with MySQL Server 5.7 and MySQL Workbench 6.3. The solution is quite simple.

1. Open MySQL Workbench or switch to the **home page** with the connections
2. Click the small **tool icon** next to the label **MySQL Connections**
3. The **Manage Server Connections** dialog appears
4. Select the connection from the list of MySQL Connections
5. The **Connection** data for this connection appear to the right
6. Switch from the **Connection** tab to **System Profile**
7. Change the entry in the **Configuration File** field
8. Click the Close button and you are done

In my case all I had to do is to change the entry from:
**%ProgramFiles%**\MySQL\MySQL Server **5.0**\my.ini
to
**%ProgramData%**\MySQL\MySQL Server **5.7**\my.ini

Comment: I never worked with MySQL Workbench 5.2. Now, with Workbench 6.3 it might be much easier, but I posted this answer after I've been searching for a solution myself because that somewhat hidden entry is really hard to find.

Comment: Please not that I not only had to change the server version from 5.0 to 5.7 but also from __%ProgramFiles%__ to __%ProgramData%__ where already a preconfigured my.ini existed.

Answer (score 9):

Try: You can change the base directory in

`Server Administration-> Manager Server Instances > Local MySQL >system Profile > Configuration file : <your dir>\my.ini` (Click the directory)

Comment: its unchangeable field, how i could make it possible to change the directory?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a New Server Instance in server administration section of Workbench. There you will be able to specify your .ini file location.

Comment: Exactly this, as soon as I deleted my old instance and registered a new one the correct .ini file was found. Jut make sure you MySQL server is running at the time so workbench knows what service to connect to.

Running Windows 7 and XAMPP by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Your Server instance is registered wrong.

When you create new server instance for server administration in workbench, there is a selected option, e.g.:

> Mysql Installation Type:
>   Window(MySQL5.0 x64 Installer Package)

If you selected a wrong one with your current OS and Server installation, it would result an incorrect base path mapping.

To solve your issue,  you can change the base directory in Server Administration-> Logging the instance -> Configuration Menu -> Configuration -> General:
1) Click the base directory checkbox
2) Input the path e.g.

> "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server
>   5.1/"

3) Click the data directory checkbox
4) Input the path e.g.

> "C:/Documents and Settings/All
>   Users/Application Data/MySQL/MySQL
>   Server 5.1/Data/"

Comment: I tried it and when clicking apply it errored out again. It can't change configuration as it can't access the configuration file...

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan, when I looked upon your question for which I was originally searching I found the answer few minutes later.

To connect them as you already probably know but a lost soul may learn from this is that the configuration file we are talking about is not presented inside MySQL. It is located in

`C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\alias`

Of course, figure it out for ourselves where your `wamp` is located if you are using it. In my case the desired file was in `alias` folder.

I hope this would help someone with my case.

Best regards and blessings.